# Simple bcrypt Register User and User Login using PHP - is this approach acceptable?

Tags: php

I am learning PHP and have been looking into a suitable way to safely store password data in MySQL.

Following advice from here ([How do you use bcrypt for hashing passwords in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php)), is this an acceptable way to deal with passwords?

The code is a very basic example and I haven't included things like error checking / checking if user already exists etc. to keep my example concise.

**Register User:**

```
$fld_email =    $_POST['fld_email'];
$fld_name =     $_POST['fld_name'];
$fld_pwd =      $_POST['fld_pwd'];

$hashToStoreInDb = password_hash($fld_pwd, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array("cost" => 11));

  $sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_a_users (fld_email
                                 , fld_name
                                 , fld_pwd
                                 , fld_date) 
                           VALUES (:fld_email
                                 , :fld_name
                                 , :fld_pwd
                                 , now())";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bindParam(':fld_email', $fld_email);
$stmt->bindParam(':fld_name', $fld_name);
$stmt->bindParam(':fld_pwd', $hashToStoreInDb);

$stmt->execute();
```

**Process Login:**

```
$fld_email    = $_POST['fld_email'];
$fld_pwd_form = $_POST['fld_pwd'];

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT fld_pwd FROM tbl_a_users WHERE fld_email = :email');
$stmt->bindParam(':email', $fld_email);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

$isPasswordCorrect = password_verify($fld_pwd_form, $row->fld_pwd);

if ($isPasswordCorrect == true) {
    // do something
} else {
    // do something else
}
```

There is no error message here, but I wanted to check with experts about whether this is an acceptable approach before I continue work on this area.

Comment: The only think I could suggest is just the `if()` part doesn't necessary to use `true` haha

Comment: You might want to try this at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks - I've asked via http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/126215/simple-bcrypt-register-user-and-user-login-using-php-is-this-approach-acceptab